# How do i send an entire xcode project to a client

Tags: xcode

I am trying to attach the project to my email - so my mentor can test the code but it doesn't let me. The project will open up but no source code.

Comment: just zip ur code and upload to dropbox and share the drop box link.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways. The first is to public your project on Github and let your mentor download the project from github. The second, and perhaps easiest for you, is to kip the entire folder containing your project files and send it to your mentor.

Please, notice that your project folder, for instaande MyProject, will contain the folder with source code, also called MyProject, the project file, MyProject.xcodeproj, the testfile folder called MyProjectTests and perhaps also a UI test folder, called MyProjectUITests. You have to zip all these folders or upload them on Github.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to upload your zipped project i.e. at [this site](http://wikisend.com/) and send the link to your mentor. Just zip your project at the topmost level.

Github is very fine, but perhaps u must spend some time to  master it

Answer (score 0):

You could try uploading the folder to Dropbox and share the link with the mentor